# Geometric invariants of a scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intuition, homology-cohomology

Following my previous question about [sheaf cohomology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54752/sheaf-cohomology-what-is-it-and-where-can-i-learn-it), I'd like to ask about its applications to algebraic geometry. I have now learned a little about homological algebra and I can see that for ordinary topological spaces $X$,
$$H^0(X, A) \cong \Gamma(X, \Delta(A))$$
where $A$ is any abelian group, $\Delta(A)$ is the constant sheaf of $A$ on $X$, and the $H^0$ appearing on the LHS refers to singular cohomology, so it is quite plausible to me that the higher cohomology groups should also coincide.

Of course, the trouble is that a scheme is more than just a topological space; in some sense the underlying space is irrelevant and simply provides a setting on which the structure sheaf can be defined. **How does one recapture the traditional geometric invariants of, say, a complex variety in the world of algebraic geometry?**

To be a bit more precise, suppose $X$ is a smooth projective algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$, viewed as a scheme. It seems highly implausible to me that $H^i(X, \mathbb{Z})$ (in the sense of either singular cohomology or sheaf cohomology) should yield anything of interest, given the coarseness of the Zariski topology. However, as I understand it, it is still possible to compute geometric invariants (e.g. Euler characteristic, genus, Betti numbers) of the associated complex manifold using the machinery of algebraic geometry. **How is this done, and why does it work?**

I really haven't learned very much about algebraic geometry (or its history), so forgive me if I'm asking questions about some very deep results!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all you are completely right abour the woefully inappropriate character of sheaf cohomology of constant sheaves on algebraic geometric varieties endowed with their Zariski topology: if a scheme (or variety) $X$ is irreducible,  all higher cohomology groups $H^i(X, \mathbb Z_X) \quad$ ($ \mathbb Z_X$= constant sheaf) vanish for $i\gt0$ because $ \mathbb Z_X$ is flabby, hence acyclic.
There are several possible remedies to this unsatisfactory situation, for example:

**Analytification**
If $X$ is defined over $\mathbb C$, there is a functorial way of associating to it a complex analytic space $X(\mathbb C)$, with a classical  topology : for example if $X$ was smooth ( a purely algebraic notion) then $X(\mathbb C)$ will be a holomorphic manifold and *a fortiori* a topological manifold. Then  you can apply all tools of algebraic topology: singular cohomology, homotopy theory,...

**Coherent cohomology**
If $X$ is projective and smooth (say), you can calculate the topological invariants of $X(\mathbb C)$ you are interested in (Euler characteristic, genus, Betti numbers) directly on $X$ by using the  cohomology of coherent sheaves like $\Omega_X^n$, the sheaf of differential $n$- forms on $X$. Let me emphasize that these calculations are made entirely in the algebraic category, that is by using the Zariski topology.

**Etale cohomology**
This is one of Grothendieck's most brilliant insights in his career.
 By slightly changing the notion of topology, Grothendieck showed that you can define a reasonable theory of cohomology with constant coefficients for *all* schemes. If the scheme happens to be a variety over $\mathbb C$, Mike Artin proved a comparison theorem to the effect that you get the same invariants as through analytification.
You might be interested by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6070/etale-cohomology-why-study-it/6078#6078) question and its answers on MathOverflow on the theme of étale cohomology, where you will also find a link to Milne's fine online free notes on the subject.

**Illustration**
Let $X$ be a complete smooth connected curve over the algebraically closed field $k$. Let us calculate its genus $g$ by the three methods above.
*Analytification:* If $k=\mathbb C$, use $rank_{\mathbb Z}H^1(X(\mathbb C),\mathbb Z)=2g$.

*Coherent cohomology :* Use the formula $g=dim_{\mathbb C}H^1(X,\mathcal O)$ or also $g=dim_{\mathbb C}H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$

*Etale cohomology:* Choose any prime    $p\neq char.k$ and use $H^1_{étale}(X,\mu_p)=(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^{2g}$, where $\mu_p$ is the sheaf on $X$ (in the étale topology) of $p$-th roots of unity.

**Bibliography**
[Neeman, Algebraic and analytic geometry](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algebraic_and_analytic_geometry.html?id=VacrAAAAYAAJ)  For analytification.
[Wells, Differential analysis on complex manifolds](http://books.google.com/books/about/Differential_analysis_on_complex_manifol.html?id=a4Tptn3EPe4C) For Hodge theory.